# unable to use attribute from a python function in another python script

Tags: python, function, join, ipc

I want to use one of the attributes returned by a function in a python script (x) into a python script (y)

The communication between both scripts works well; I can get functions and attributes, but doesn't allow me to attributes returned by a function.

Here is how I worked:

**x.py**

```
def func():
    b = 10
    a = 15
    return [a,b]
c = 20
```

---

**y.py**

```
from x import func
import x
print (x.c)
print (func.b)
```

I get the "c" value and the following error `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'b'`

I have tried also to print `x.b`, and I've got `AttributeError: module 'WorkingLSTM' has no attribute 'b'`

Thanks in advance

Comment: You cannot call a variable set in a function unless the funtion returns it.

Comment: those **are not attributes**. Those are **local variables**.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga , yes, for this question I just put local variables, in my actual script, b is a predicted time series from an LSTM network

Comment: @Nour why is that relevant? Regardless, those are not attributes.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga ,  thanks for the information ^^
I'm not sure of understanding your question, but I accepted the answer because all I wanted was accessing to the data generated, and that the method provided worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not allowed, you have to call the function to get the value from the functions returned list.

```
a, b = func()
print(b)
# or just...
print(func()[1])
```

PS: It's "not allowed" because it doesn't make sense in any way; when there is no function call, there is not variable b at all. You might take a look at classes, they can hold static variables.

Answer (score 3):

The way to call **func** is by using `func()`, which would give you [a,b].

example:

```
funcResult = func()

a = funcResult[0]
b = funcResult[1]
```

**funcResults** is the return value from **func()**, that is the list **[a,b]**.

Comment: calling the return value of a function call `newFunc` might be misleading.
It might especially be misleading for beginners, as the result (the return value of func()) is not a function, but a list with two values

Answer (score 2):

you cannot access local variables of a function.
these variables exist only during the the time where func is executed and are destroyed afterwards.

You can of course call the function and look at the result, but the result is just a list with two values

```
rslt = func()
print("A = ", rslt[0])
print("B = ", rslt[1])
```

Answer (score 2):

The variable was declared inside a function making it a local variable and as such it can"t be accessed outside the function.

The variable is declared outside of the function making it a global variable and is not in anyway tied to your function.

The concept of attributes relates to Classes and you are dealing with a function so you might have to treat it as a class object.

If you are concerned bout accessing the local variables, you might as well do this:

y.py

```
from x import *

d = func()       # func returns a list which is now 
                         # identified/referenced by variable d

# displays the elements in the list using index position
print(d[0])
print(d[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use attributes, you may create a callable class instead of function:

```
class Func:
    def __init__(self):
        self.b = 10
        self.a = 15
    def __call__():
        return [self.a, self.b]
func = Func()
```

Answer (score 1):

Python has the concept of the scope. Local variables have no effect outside the function.
If you want to use it, use class and `self` or make getter function(but it's not Pythonic).

**x.py**

```py
class X:
    def __init__(self):
        self.b = 10
        self.a = 15
        self.c = 20

    def func(self):
        return [self.a, self.b]
```

**y.py**

```py
from x import X

x = X()
print(x.c)
print(x.func()[1])
```